# Put django file object into tikka server

Tags: python, django, apache-tika

In my project I have receiving multiple files using `request.FILES.getlist('filedname')` and saving it using `django forms save` method. Again reading the same files using `tika` server api of python:

```
def read_by_tika(self, path):
    '''file reading using tika server'''
    parsed = parser.from_file(str(path))
    contents = (parsed["content"].encode('utf-8'))
    return contents
```

Is there any way to directly put list files getting from `request.FILES` to  `tikka` server without saving it on hard disk.

Comment: Did you mean [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/)? Please add a link to `read_by_tikka()` API docs.

Comment: Yes Apache Tika

Comment: def read_by_tikka(self, path):
        '''file reading using tika server'''
        parsed = parser.from_file(str(path))
        contents = (parsed["content"].encode('utf-8'))
        return contents@Udi

Comment: I have edited your question above

Answer (score 2):

If the files are small, try using tika's [`.from_buffer()`](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python#using-a-buffer) with `file.read()`.  However, files over 2.5 MBs are anyway saved to temporary files by django, see [Where uploaded data is stored](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/#where-uploaded-data-is-stored).  In this case use [`read_by_tika(file.temporary_file_path())`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile.temporary_file_path).  See also [file upload settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#file-uploads)